# LCD rated at max 5.5 V used at 6V

Tags: ratings, character-lcd

I'm trying to use an LCD (DEM16101) from a uC.
At some point I've connected it's power input to a 6V battery (above its 5.5 V max rating).

I can't initialize it properly so at this point I'm wondering - how can I tell if I've fried it?

Comment: Next time use a diode (1N4007) in series with your power supply to drop the voltage from 6V to aprox. 5.3V

Comment: @m.Alin diode voltage drop varies base on current draw. Some lcds only take 10 or 20 mA, so the diode might only drop 0.1 or 0.2v (Nokia 5510 lcd, 1n4001, in my experience).

Comment: @passerby At 10 mA the voltage drop of a 1N4001 would be 0.6 V, according to [the datasheet](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/1N/1N4001.pdf); but you're right in mentioning than one should take into account the current through the diode

Comment: @m.Alin I just checked a couple of different manufacturer datasheets, you are right. 0.6v ish at 0.01 Amps. 0.7v at 0.1A. I need to double check my last circuit then because it's not working as it should. (radioshack diodes)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Edit: There is some argument over Maximum and Absolute Maximum values in the comments. Personally, I would still not trust the device to operate correctly, even though it has not reached or exceeded the Absolute Maximum rating. A couple comments have been made that I am incorrect in my interpretation of the datasheet. YMMV*

You can tell you've fried it because you've over-volted it. I just checked the spec sheet, and 5.5V is indeed the maximum the display can tolerate. So connecting it to 6V has killed it. If you want to be *really* be sure you've fried, put the controller IC under an electron microscope or something and view the damage that way. Otherwise, you'll just have to assume it's gone to electronics heaven. :(

IMHO, it is a waste of time to even try to troubleshoot the display now. Even if it did work, it might stop working at any point in the future. It is no longer reliable - time to replace it! :)

Comment: datasheet page 5 show absolute max of 7 V. http://www.soselectronic.hu/a_info/resource/d/dem/dem16101syh.pdf

Comment: Right, and operating voltage max 5.5V. So anything between 5.5V and 7V is "unknown". It might work, it might not...

Comment: @dextorb - "unknown" as in software undefined? Meaning it might still work at 5V?

Comment: @diciu - "Unknown" in the sense that it depends on manufacturing tolerances and may vary from device to device whether it will work between 5.5V and 7V. It's not recommended to roll the dice when it comes to 'Absolute Maximum' specifications.

Comment: That contradicts what you say by telling OP that connecting it to 6v killed it.

Comment: It *might* fry at 6V. And if it's not working now, then you *have to assume* it's fried. At 7V, you *know* for sure it's dead. I do not see a contradiction.

Comment: No, you never *know* you fried it, only that it is a possibility when absolute max specs are exceeded.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Absolute means absolute. The area of *possibility* is between maximum and absolute. I understand what you're saying, but that is trending into statistical analysis. From an engineering standpoint, as a designer of a system, to *you the designer*, the device is as-good-as-dead at 7V. I hope that clarifies what I'm trying to say.

Comment: @dextorb it did not fry at 6V.  7V is the absolute maximum rating.  It may not run properly at 6V, but it will not be damaged if absmax is not exceeded.  That is what "Absolute Maximum" means.  If it can be damaged by 6V, then what is the point of absmax spec?

Comment: @markrages What is the point of saying 5.5V is the maximum then? Why not just say Supply voltage 0-7V. After 7V, destruction? Why is there a gap between 5.5V max and 7V absolute max?

Comment: @dext0rb The part may not operate within spec (or operate at all) in the 5.5->7.0V range, but it will not be destroyed.  That's the difference between operating and absmax specs.

Comment: @markrages If that's the case, both the answers here are wrong then...Is it not possible if the supply voltage was connected to 6V for a long period of time, something could have been damaged?

Comment: @dext0rb, not possible according to the datasheet.  But carelessness with the supply connections could certainly damage the display.  Notice that if any input or the bias voltage V0 exceeds Vdd by more than 0.3V, damage may occur.

Comment: @dext0rb: Many data sheets include a note to the effect that extended exposure to near-absolute-maximum conditions may affect device reliability.  I think the idea behind AMR in many cases is to provide guidance as to what sorts of protection devices are needed to protect devices from various adverse conditions.  It's easier to design a device that will clamp an ESD hit to 6.9 volts without wasting power at 5 volts, than to design one that will clamp it to 5.01 volts while still not wasting power at 5.00).

Answer (score 7):

You can't tell whether you fried it, that would be proving a negative.  However, you should *assume* you fried it, especially since it doesn't appear to work anymore.  You violated a absolute maximum spec, so really shouldn't be surprised.  Violating such a spec is no *guarantee* of damage, but you can no longer rely on any other specs.  Even if a over-stressed unit *appears* to work, it might be damaged in subtle ways and fail sometimes in some regions of its operating range.

You screwed up.  Toss out the damaged device, learn the lesson, and move on.  Trying to get anything useful from this device will only result in lots of frustration and probably no useful result.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've accepted dextorb's as he was the first one to point out the 'throw it' solution.